# Getting "This key is already associated with an element of this collection" while importing the pages using content porter 2009

Tags: content-porter-2009

All went good to my test server, however while importing pages, it is giving below error.

```
5/9/2013 10:39:21 AM    [Information]   Import started
5/9/2013 10:39:21 AM    [Information]   Importing System Administration items
5/9/2013 10:39:22 AM    [Error] This key is already associated with an element of this collection
5/9/2013 10:39:22 AM    [Information]   Process failed
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is mentioned in Elena's SDL Tridion World article on '[Using Content Porter 2009 SP1 for DTAP](http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/using-content-porter-2009-sp1-for-dtap-5.aspx)'

In the 'Troubleshooting' section, Elena recommends you "**check for circular references and import the items with least dependencies first**".

Can you try importing items at a more granular level, with those items that are depended on (Schemas, Keywords, etc.) coming in first?

Comment: Thanks for reply, the pages which I am importing from DEV are new. What type of circular dependencies should be take care...as there is only one component and CT attached and all the schema used is already placed, when I create pages manually all goes good...I can get my all the content ported data.

Comment: I would try to import the items in the following order:  Categories & Keywords, Embedded Schemas, Schemas, Organisations items (Folders & Structure Groups), Components, Component Templates, Page Template and then the Pages.  If some of these are already created (and you're 100% that they've not changed) then you could skip them.  There's some more background here too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11482824/197993

Answer (score 2):

I faced this kind issue on Content Porter 2009 SP1. And we have applied a hotfix available on SDL Tridion World and issue get Resolved.

Comment: Can you name the hotfix? Provide a link?

Comment: CP_3.1.0.75326_tcm89-20162